# Asynchronous HTTP server side browser request

Tags: php, apache, browser

Is it possible to make an HTTP request for some HTML pages from a PHP script where the PHP script resides on the same server as the HTML pages? This script has to be running all the time while server is up.

The PHP script must make the request exactly every one second.

I tried a cron job and the accuracy was not sufficient.

I have used nodejs in a javascript routine and that works for me but I would rather have a server side script do the requests.

I want to use an asynchronous method of making the request so as the HTTP request does not interfere with the timing.

I don't want to have a computer which is always on just to be on that page all the time. So I need some other solution using the server where site is hosted.

Comment: what's the reason you need it ?

Comment: na engleskom cu, ako nije problem :D
I did something in php, i figured out it would be best if it was in nodejs because it has asynchronous calling. So I thought to make javascript and setinterval to workaround php and just make that page opened all the time.

Comment: @MarkoMackic English only please.

Comment: @PedroLobito not a problem :)

Comment: Are you able to use a cron job that runs a script each time?

Comment: @MarkoMackic there's always google translate ;) but it's not very useful for future users...tks.

Comment: @DraganPeric can't help much without details about script and source code :)

Comment: Well it has to be every second and accurate, but cron is not that good with accuracy.

Comment: Please provide more details :) And someone might be able to help :)

Comment: If it needs to be *accurate*, you shouldn't be using a "fake request" either. There's likely an entirely different approach which you should be using here, but without knowing what you're actually trying to do nobody can tell you what that is.

Comment: @deceze I wasn't asking how to solve my problem, just is it possible to fake a request that would stay opened all the time. Simple answer with YES and NO is enough. Although I left it unanswered in case someone tells something which would gave me an idea solving my problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a tested asynchronous PHP request.
It can be run from the same server or any server.
Accuracy should be within a millisecond.
Reducing usleep(1000) will increase accuracy but decrease CPU availability. 
**Before down voting my answer** please make sure you understand what I have done.
In my testing I monitored the CPU usage.  Typical usage was 0.1% CPU and max 0.2%

In my script below this is the HTTP Request Header:

```
$http = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\n\r\n";
```

It can be edited to include anything you  need in the header.
 
To add User Agent:

```
$ua = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'
```

Then add crlf and the $ua

```
$http = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\n$ua\r\n\r\n";
```

### Test Scripts

This PHP script is http://ispeedlink.com/so/asyncTimer/index.php
It makes an HTTP request to http://ispeedlink.com/so/asyncTimer/log.php "exactly" every second

```
<?php
$host = 'ispeedlink.com';
$path = '/so/asyncTimer/log.php';
$http = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\n\r\n";
$cntr = 0;
while(true){
  if(((microtime(true) * 1000)  % 10) < 1){ // make http request as soon as system clock passes one second + 10mS
    $stream = stream_socket_client("$host:80", $errno,$errstr, 100,STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT); 
    if ($stream) {
      fwrite($stream, $http);
    }
    else { 
      file_put_contents('error.txt',"Failed: $errno,$errstr\n",FILE_APPEND);
    }
    usleep(990000);  // wait 990 milliseconds so microtime() * 1000 % 10  will be greater than 10 until next second
    $cntr++;
    if($cntr > 9){break;}
  }
  usleep(1000);  // release CPU for at least a millisecond.

}

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
readfile('log.txt');
file_put_contents('log.txt',"\n",FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

For this test I added a counter to allow the script to make just 10 requests:

```
$cntr++;
if($cntr > 9){break;}
```

This is log.php which is requested from index.php every second.

```
<?php
$time = microtime(true) . "\n";
file_put_contents('log.txt',$time,FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

In my Browser I made a request to `http://ispeedlink.com/so/asyncTimer/`
two times with a pause in between.

Here is the log.txt

```
1462802817.32
1462802818.32
1462802819.32
1462802820.32
1462802821.32
1462802822.32
1462802823.32
1462802824.32
1462802825.32
1462802826.33

1462802836.72
1462802837.71
1462802838.72
1462802839.72
1462802840.72
1462802841.72
1462802842.72
1462802843.72
1462802844.72
1462802845.71
```

If you need to see the response from the request .
 
Add this line of code after the request:

```
$sockets[] = $stream;
```

Which will then look like this:

```
if ($stream) {
  fwrite($stream, $http);
  $sockets[] = $stream; 
}
```

And add this routine
The response for each request will be in the $response array.

```
while (count($sockets)) {
  $read = $sockets; 
  stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, 100);
  if (count($read)) {
    foreach ($read as $r) { 
      $id = array_search($r, $sockets); 
      $data = fread($r, $buffer_size); 
      if (strlen($data) == 0) { 
        fclose($r); 
        unset($sockets[$id]);
      } 
      else {
        $response[$id] .= $data; 
      }
    }
  }
  else { 
    break;
  }
}
```

CPU usage stats:

```
%CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
0.2  0.0 233524 11236 ?        S    11:10   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/usr/public_html/so/asyncTimer/index.php
0.1  0.0 233524 11236 ?        S    11:10   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/usr/public_html/so/asyncTimer/index.php
0.1  0.0 233524 11236 ?        S    11:10   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/usr/public_html/so/asyncTimer/index.php
0.1  0.0 233524 11236 ?        S    11:10   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/usr/public_html/so/asyncTimer/index.php
0.1  0.0 233524 11236 ?        S    11:10   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/usr/public_html/so/asyncTimer/index.php
0.1  0.0 233524 11236 ?        S    11:10   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/usr/public_html/so/asyncTimer/index.php
0.1  0.0 233524 11236 ?        S    11:10   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/usr/public_html/so/asyncTimer/index.php
0.1  0.0 233524 11236 ?        S    11:10   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/usr/public_html/so/asyncTimer/index.php
0.1  0.0 233524 11236 ?        S    11:10   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/usr/public_html/so/asyncTimer/index.php
0.1  0.0 233524 11236 ?        S    11:10   0:00 /usr/bin/php /home/usr/public_html/so/asyncTimer/index.php
0
```

Comment: @missunderstood I guess you misunderstood the question ***"Is it possible to make a fake client browser request for some page using the server the site is on?"***

Comment: @missunderstood I'm not a hater who gives downvotes, don't worry :D if I like the answer i give it thumbs up, otherwise ignore it. You didn't answer my question but you did gave me an idea how to solve my problem. This is very constructive an I will try it out.

Comment: And that is what this routine does.  I will add an example.

Comment: @PedroLobito Is that not what I did? I added the results of my testing.